# Session check prior to controller method in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm not very experienced with Spring MVC and I have a feeling like this is something trivial (well, in ASP.NET it pretty much is), but I can't find any solution for this, so I have to ask.

Say I have different controllers, all of which check their own stuff on every method...

```
@Controller
public class FirstController {
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(HttpSession s) {
         if(!s.getAttribute("something").equals("some stuff"))
             return "redirect:home";
         return "foo";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public String bar(HttpSession s) {
         if(!s.getAttribute("something").equals("some stuff"))
             return "redirect:home";
         return "bar";
    }
}

@Controller
public class AnotherController {
    @RequestMapping("/john")
    public String john(HttpSession s) {
         if(Integer.parseInt(s.getAttribute("somethingElse")) == 42)
             return "redirect:home";
         return "john";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/doe")
    public String doe(HttpSession s) {
         if(Integer.parseInt(s.getAttribute("somethingElse")) == 42)
             return "redirect:home";
         return "doe";
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make every controller do "its thing" before actually invoking what the controller "should" do. So Controllers could simply be something like:

```
public String foo() { return "foo"; }
```

while I know that in the background the if statement is being invoked before the actual method is fired off.

Any short example or documentation link (or pretty much anything that suits this request) is more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the usage of @ControllerAdvice: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice

You could combine the @ControllerAdvice to intercept execution of all of your Controller methods before execution, along with your own base Controller class that you create that has a common method like public String evaluate(), which you then implement in each sub-classed controller and invoke in the @ControllerAdvice.